# Crontab: run two commands only if first command was ok

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash-script which checks if some files exist and copies them to other places. If files not there then it exits with status code 4.

If status code is 0 then two php-scripts should run and work with the copied files. But I do not know how to tell that third command (second php script) should run only if first command was 0.

The script which copies files:

```
/var/www/dms-live/import-xknddb.sh >> /var/log/importer/import-cron.log
```

The first php script:

```
php -f "xknddb-import.php" live k000 >> /var/log/importer/live.xknddb.log
```

The second php script:

```
php -f "xknddb-import.php" test k000 >> /var/log/importer/test.xknddb.log
```

The two php-scripts can run at same time, so i tried this one:

```
/var/www/dms-live/import-xknddb.sh >> /var/log/importer/import-cron.log && php -f "xknddb-import.php" live k000 >> /var/log/importer/live.xknddb.log &  php -f "xknddb-import.php" testAll k000 >> /var/log/importer/test.xknddb.log &
```

first php-script does not run if first command fails. But second php script always starts to run.

Is it possible to group the two php-scripts or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group the two php scripts together with a parenthesis `()`, or brackets `{}` if you don't want to open a subshell:

```
$ false && (echo "Hello" & echo "World") 


$ true && (echo "Hello" & echo "World") 
Hello 
World
```

In your case:

```
/var/www/dms-live/import-xknddb.sh >> /var/log/importer/import-cron.log && (php -f "xknddb-import.php" live k000 >> /var/log/importer/live.xknddb.log &  php -f "xknddb-import.php" testAll k000 >> /var/log/importer/test.xknddb.log &)
```

Comment: You should use code blocks `{ }` instead of parens so you don't needlessly open a subshell.